# Build Step Progress Bar (css and jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar, multi-step

[image]

You've seen iterations of this type of progress bar on sites like paypal.  How does one go about setting this up using `CSS` and `jquery`? I have 4 pages and each page is a step... so 4 steps.

Comment: Why jQuery though? Will it animate or something?

Answer (score 56):

I have searched for a solution that will visualize process steps in my web application. I have found the following excellent write-up by Stephen A Thomas:

Tracking Progress in Pure CSS ([Original Link now dead](https://jsfiddle.net/5qqh3wtj/))

In his approach Thomas even gets away with just using CSS - no Javascript! 
In an essence the following CSS code from his article does the trick for me:

```
    <style>

    <!-- Progress with steps -->

    ol.progtrckr {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ol.progtrckr li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 3em;
    }

    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
    ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }

    ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
        color: black;
        border-bottom: 4px solid yellowgreen;
    }
    ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo {
        color: silver; 
        border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
    }

    ol.progtrckr li:after {
        content: "\00a0\00a0";
    }
    ol.progtrckr li:before {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -2.5em;
        float: left;
        left: 50%;
        line-height: 1em;
    }
    ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:before {
        content: "\2713";
        color: white;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        height: 1.2em;
        width: 1.2em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 1.2em;
    }
    ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
        content: "\039F";
        color: silver;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        bottom: -1.6em;
    }

</style>
```

As well as HTML tags from his example (I use Grails GSP pages to generate tags and 'done/todo' class dynamically):

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="5">
    <li class="progtrckr-done">Order Processing</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done">Pre-Production</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done">In Production</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done">Shipped</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Delivered</li>
</ol>
```

Hope it helps. Works pretty well for me.

---

**UPDATE**: The following (shortened) version also works well.

```
    ol.progtrckr {
        display: table;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    ol.progtrckr li {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 3em;
    }
    ... and the rest of the CSS ...

    <ol class="progtrckr">
        ...
    </ol>
```

`display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%` ensure that the list items are automatically sized equally as long as the content does not overflow.  There is no need to use `data-progtrckr-steps` and its associated CSS.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!

Comment: Really good solution ,especially after the update. I like how to get bigger and smaller to fit the size of scree,Though it does break on mobiles

Comment: I wish it was responsive because it's otherwise brilliant and looks really good.

Comment: I didnt like the white space between each step. So I added a float to each <li> and clear it with ol:after element.

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 25):

There are a lot of very nice answers on this page and I googled for some more, but none of the answers ticked all the checkboxes on my wish list:

- CSS only, no Javascript
- Stick to Tom Kenny's [Best Design Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/)
- Layout like the other answers
- Each step has a name and a number
- Responsive layout: font size independent
- Fluid layout: the list and its items scale with the available width
- The names and numbers are centered in their block
- The "done" color goes up to and including the active item, but not past it.
- The active item should stand out graphically

So I mixed the code of several examples, fixed the things that I needed and here is the result:

[image: Progress Tracker v2]

I used the following CSS and HTML:

```css
/* Progress Tracker v2 */
ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }

.progress {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.progress li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.progress .name {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .step {
    color: black;
    border: 3px solid silver;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 0;
}

.progress .step span {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .active .name,
.progress .active .step span {
    opacity: 1;
}

.progress .step:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 0.4em;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.6em;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progress .step:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 0.4em;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.6em;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
    display: none;
}

.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
    display: none;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .done .step:before,
.progress .done .step:after,
.progress .active .step,
.progress .active .step:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .active .step {
    border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!-- Progress Tracker v2 -->
<ol class="progress" data-steps="4">
    <li class="done">
        <span class="name">Foo</span>
        <span class="step"><span>1</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="done">
        <span class="name">Bar</span>
        <span class="step"><span>2</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <span class="name">Baz</span>
        <span class="step"><span>3</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="name">Quux</span>
        <span class="step"><span>4</span></span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

As can be seen in the example above, there are now two list item classes to take note of: `active` and `done`. Use `class="active"` for the current step, use `class="done"` for all steps before it.

Also note the `data-steps="4"` in the `ol` tag; set this to the total number of steps to apply the correct size to all list items.

Feel free to play around with the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLwgrym8/). Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome work.  I updated the fiddle to use `flex` rather than float and `data-steps`, I also implamented a css "counter" for the step numbers. https://jsfiddle.net/usg6jyc5/

Comment: Love how your example is more dynamic and flexible, @Chad. Definitely an improvement for modern browsers!

Comment: If steps' names are too long, resizing window may cause the progress bar to "break" into segments. Precisely, the long text will be split in multiple lines and the `step` element underneath it will be moved down, messing up the layout. To avoid this, if you know the number of lines in which the text will be split, you can add a `height` attribute to `.progress .name` (e.g. I set it to 3em, having a maximum of two lines in case of resizing) to make room for the other lines.

Comment: Great, It helped me a lot, Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to make one:

http://24ways.org/2008/checking-out-progress-meters

Here are some inspiration examples:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/15/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/

Answer (score 13):

This is how I have achieved it using purely CSS and HTML (no JavaScript/images etc.).

http://jsfiddle.net/tuPrn/

It gracefully degrades in most browsers (I do need to add in a fix for lack of last-of-type in  < IE9).

Comment: No javascript? Then why does the fiddle have MooTools selected?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirements to create a kind of step progress tracker so I created a JavaScript plugin for that purpose. Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er_sanjeevrai/hvw60bvj/) for the demo for this step progress tracker. You can access its code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sanjeev5370/steps-progress-tracker/tree/master) as well.

What it basically does is, it takes the json data(in a particular format described below) as input and creates the progress tracker based on that. Highlighted steps indicates the completed steps.

It's html will somewhat look like shown below with default CSS but you can customize it as per the theme of your application. There is an option to show tool-tip text for each steps as well.

**Here is some code snippet for that:**

```
//container div 
<div id="tracker1" style="width: 700px">
</div>

//sample JSON data
var sampleJson1 = {
ToolTipPosition: "bottom",
data: [{ order: 1, Text: "Foo", ToolTipText: "Step1-Foo", highlighted: true },
    { order: 2, Text: "Bar", ToolTipText: "Step2-Bar", highlighted: true },
    { order: 3, Text: "Baz", ToolTipText: "Step3-Baz", highlighted: false },
    { order: 4, Text: "Quux", ToolTipText: "Step4-Quux", highlighted: false }]
};    

//Invoking the plugin
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tracker1").progressTracker(sampleJson1);
    });
```

Hopefully it will be useful for somebody else as well!

[image]

Comment: How about vertical?  From top to bottom.

Comment: Any chance to convert it as vertical in Phone or tabs and horizontal in PC according to screen size?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

1. Create **jQuery .progressbar()** to load a div into a progress bar.
2. Create the step *title* on the bottom of the progress bar. Position them with **CSS**.
3. Then I create function in **jQuery** that change the *value* of the **progressbar** everytime user move on to next step.

**HTML**

```
<div id="divProgress"></div>
<div id="divStepTitle">
    <span class="spanStep">Step 1</span> <span class="spanStep">Step 2</span> <span class="spanStep">Step 3</span>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnPrev" name="btnPrev" value="Prev" />
<input type="button" id="btnNext" name="btnNext" value="Next" />
```

**CSS**

```
#divProgress
{
    width: 600px;
}

#divStepTitle
{
    width: 600px;
}

.spanStep
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var progress = 0;

$(function({
    //set step progress bar
    $("#divProgress").progressbar();

    //event handler for prev and next button
    $("#btnPrev, #btnNext").click(function(){
        step($(this));
    });
});

function step(obj)
{
    //switch to prev/next page
    if (obj.val() == "Prev")
    {
        //set new value for progress bar
        progress -= 20;
        $("#divProgress").progressbar({ value: progress });

        //do extra step for showing previous page
    }
    else if (obj.val() == "Next")
    {
        //set new value for progress bar
        progress += 20;
        $("#divProgress").progressbar({ value: progress });

        //do extra step for showing next page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweeked @Patrick Atoon answer and created a razor component to display a current status bar from an Enum.  This worked really well.

Razor component page - CaseStatus.razor:

```
<p>Case Status Tracker</p>
<ol class="casestatus">
    @foreach (var s in statusBars)
    {
        <li class="@s.State">
            <span class="name">@s.Name</span>
            <span class="step"><span class="count"></span></span>
        </li>
    }
</ol>
<hr />

@code {
    //Enum Status Names
    private string[] status;
    //Current Status - best if parameter
    private Status currentStatus;
    //List of Names and progress states - done, active, (empty)
    private List<statusBar> statusBars { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //Test current status (progress)
        currentStatus = Status.Engineering;
        statusBars = new List<statusBar>();
        status = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status));
        var statusval = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<int>().ToList();
        for(int i=0; i < status.Length; i++){
            var value = statusval[i];
            string state = "done";
            if (((int)currentStatus) == value)
            {
                state = "active";
            } else {
                if (((int)currentStatus) < value)
                {
                    state = "";
                }
            }
            statusBars.Add(new statusBar()
                {
                    Name = status[i],
                    State = state
                });
        }
    }
    public class statusBar
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
    public enum Status
    {
        Request = 0,
        Submitted = 1,
        Engineering = 2,
        InApproval = 3,
        Approved = 4,
        Production = 5,
        Complete = 6
    }

}
```

CaseStatus.razor.css:

```
/* casestatus Tracker v2.1 */
.casestatus {
    counter-reset: li;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .casestatus li {
        flex-grow: 1;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .casestatus .name {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    .casestatus .step {
        color: black;
        border: 3px solid silver;
        background-color: silver;
        border-radius: 50%;
        line-height: 2;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .casestatus .step span.count:before {
            opacity: 0.3;
            content: counter(li);
            counter-increment: li
        }

    .casestatus .active .name,
    .casestatus .active .step span {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .casestatus .step:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: silver;
        height: 0.4em;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.8em;
        left: -0.76em;
    }

    .casestatus .step:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: silver;
        height: 0.4em;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.8em;
        right: -0.76em;
    }

    .casestatus li:first-of-type .step:before {
        display: none;
    }

    .casestatus li:last-of-type .step:after {
        display: none;
    }

    .casestatus .done .step,
    .casestatus .done .step:before,
    .casestatus .done .step:after,
     .casestatus .active .step, 
    .casestatus .done + .active .step:before {
        background-color: yellowgreen;
    }

    .casestatus .done .step,
    .casestatus .active .step {
        border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
    }
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is use the same trick often use for hovering on buttons.  Prepare an image that has 2 parts: (1) a top half which is greyed out, meaning incomplete, and (2) a bottom half which is colored in, meaning completed.  Use the same image 4 times to make up the 4 steps of the progress bar, and align top for incomplete steps, and align bottom for incomplete steps.

In order to take advantage of image alignment, you'd have to use the image as the background for 4 divs, rather than using the img element.

This is the CSS for background image alignment:

```
div.progress-incomplete {
  background-position: top;
}
div.progress-finished {
  background-position: bottom;
}
```