# How can I make a jquery/css progression bar that reflects step by step form progression?

Tags: jquery, progress

I see a lot of example progress bars that show the progression bar being filled up. However, I would just like to know how I could make a progress reflect step by step form progress. A good example of what I would want can be seen [Here](http://planner.builtbybuffalo.com/step-1/). Any helpful code or examples/demos from other pages would be good to have.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You have to at least show us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ProgressBars/ there is css

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213753/build-step-progress-bar-css-and-jquery

Comment: @riwette: I actually use that progress bar in my own app.  However, I think he's after discrete steps rather than % complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like the Buffalo one, just have a look at how *they* do it.

First they define a div like this:

```
<div id="progress">
    <div id="complete" class="s1">
        <div id="marker"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then they use CSS to render the div based on the progress (which is controlled with class="s1" and so on).

```
/**
 * PROGRESS
 */
#progress,#complete {
    width: 520px;
    margin: 1px 0 19px;
    height: 32px;
    background:url(/img/backgrounds/progress.png);
    position:relative;
}
#complete {
    background-position: 0px 57px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#complete #marker {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -26px;
    background:url(/img/backgrounds/markers.png);
    width: 26px;
    height: 32px;
}
#progress .s1 {
    width: 19px;
}
#progress .s2 {
    width:111px;
}
#progress .s3 {
    width:203px;
}
#progress .s4 {
    width:295px;
}
#progress .s5 {
    width:386px;
}
#progress .s6 {
    width:478px;
}
#progress .s2 #marker {
    background-position: -26px 0;
}
#progress .s3 #marker {
    background-position: -52px 0;
}
#progress .s4 #marker {
    background-position: -78px 0;
}
#progress .s5 #marker {
    background-position: -104px 0;
}
#progress .s6 #marker {
    background-position: -130px 0;
}
```

The CSS manipulates images to show the desired state

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would any Jquery be necessary in this? I don't necessarily need animation. I just need to show that the user's progression through each page.

Comment: No jQuery required.  In fact, no JavaScript required.  This is pure CSS.  On each page you just update `class="s1"` to `class="s2"` and so forth.  You'll need to create your own images and change the values of `background-position` and `width` in the CSS to match the size of your own images.