# how to make vertical progress path using css

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

I wonder how to make a progress bar or more like a progress path using HTML, CSS and Js

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764317/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-css-progression-bar-that-reflects-step-by-step-form-prog) this is absolutely fine but I want it vertically something like this in the image 
[image]

which is gradually filled as user completes the assigned tasks.
or if any library available for the same please tell me. I searched a lot but didn't found anything satisfying my need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@NGLN's answer is simpler than mine, but I made a fiddle for it and added in functionality for lighting up nodes!

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/theoperatore/erLbLf2q/)

```js
var list = document.getElementById('progress'),
    next = document.getElementById('next'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    children = list.children,
    completed = 0;

// simulate activating a node
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    // count the number of completed nodes.
    completed = (completed === 0) ? 1 : completed + 2;
    if (completed > children.length) return;
    
    // for each node that is completed, reflect the status
    // and show a green color!
    for (var i = 0; i < completed; i++) {
        children[i].children[0].classList.remove('grey');
        children[i].children[0].classList.add('green');
        
        // if this child is a node and not divider, 
        // make it shine a little more
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            children[i].children[0].classList.add('activated');            
        }
    }
    
}, false);

// clear the activated state of the markers
clear.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].children[0].classList.remove('green');
        children[i].children[0].classList.remove('activated');
        children[i].children[0].classList.add('grey');
    }
    completed = 0;
}, false);
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { 
    padding: 15px; 
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input[type="button"] {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.node {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.activated {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(194, 255, 194, 0.8);
}

.divider {
    height: 40px;
    width: 2px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    transition: all 800ms ease;
}

li p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1px;
}

.green{ background-color: rgba(92, 184, 92, 1); }
.grey { background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 1); }
```

```html
<ul id="progress">
    <li><div class="node grey"></div><p>The First Thing!</p></li>
    <li><div class="divider grey"></div></li>
    <li><div class="node grey"></div><p>The Second Thing!</p></li>
    <li><div class="divider grey"></div></li>
    <li><div class="node grey"></div><p>The Third Thing!</p></li>
    <li><div class="divider grey"></div></li>
    <li><div class="node grey"></div><p>The Fourth Thing!</p></li>
    <li><div class="divider grey"></div></li>
    <li><div class="node grey"></div><p>The Last Thing!</p></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Next" id="next"/>
<input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.progress {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
.progress li {
  border-left: 0.2em solid black;
  padding: 0 0 0.1em 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.progress li::before {
  content: "•";
  font-size: 2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.21em;
  top: -0.45em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="progress">
    <li>Earth</li>
    <li>Land masses</li>
    <li>Mountains</li>
    <li>Guangxi</li>
    <li>Airport runway</li>
</ol>
```