# Horizontal alignment of unknown div width

Tags: css

I would like to align div inside parent div to center horizontally for div with unknown width and dynamic content (will wary from use case to use case.

I have read that `margin: auto;` usually is usually solution here, but it requires set of width which is unknown for me compile-time. `text-align: center` does't work for div inside parent div.

**Fiddle example**

Here is a [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vAG9g/).

**My two questions**

1. I would like the three circles to be aligned to the middle. Number of circles can vary from zero to many.
2. Another related questions is how I can make the progress bar have a minimum width (for instance when having only one, two or three steps) and strech to right and left when adding more steps? Here is (very bad) illustration in Paint.

[image]

As a note I would like this to work for IE 8 as well.

Comment: You mean, fill out the empty space between those circles?

Comment: Take a look at his example, is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/vAG9g/4/ ?

Comment: Thats correct, @user3529729. But I can't see in the Fiddle example that this is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want something like this? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vAG9g/1/)

```
.progressbar{
    top: 0; 
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: #00bbee; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 45px; 
    left: 0;
    text-align:center // added this line for centering the content   
}

.steps {
    display: inline-block; // and this line for auto-aligning center your child elements
}
```

Comment: This seems like solving my question #1! I have tried so many alternatives so I might misunderstood that text-align: center couldn't be a part of the solution. Do you have any tip on question #2? Thanks!

Comment: Note that this won't work in IE8 without proper `DOCTYPE` and on lower version without some workarounds (if you care about that)

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to understand what you mean by your second question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I have tried to detail my question. Please see if this helps.

Comment: I just came across on following thread that actually tries to crate step progress bar with pure html and css, which is very similar to what I'm trying to achieve here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213753/build-step-progress-bar-css-and-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Your first question can be solved by applying 
`text-align: center` to the top wrapper and changing the `display` of the steps wrapper to `inline-block`

Regarding the second question, I'm not sure that this is exactly what you meant - but it can be solved by moving the line out of the steps wrapper and positioning it at the vertical center of the whole bar using

```
position: absolute;
height: 2px;
margin-top: -1px;
top: 50%;
left: 0:
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
```

Example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAG9g/5/)

note that I also changed your html because there was some unnecessary tags there

For IE8 support check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working) (the only problematic issue here is the use of `inline-block`

Comment: Thanks, but for question 2 it's not exactly what I was searching for. Please see my updated explanation with illustration.

Comment: in this case you will have to manually handle the situation (I don't see any clear rules regarding the spread of the circle - for example - 2 and 3 fill the exact same space)