# How to Update a Class in HTML given a new Firebase response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firebase

I copied and pasted the code from the following Progress Tracker thread.
[Build Step Progress Bar (css and jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213753/build-step-progress-bar-css-and-jquery)

Based on an update from my Firebase server, I would like to update the `<li class = "progtrckr-todo":` to `<li class = "progtrckr-done":`

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="3">
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Washing</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Drying</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Ready for Pickup</li>
</ol>
```

How do I update the class in HTML given a new response from my Firebase database?

Thanks!

Comment: @rodamn No need for a web server with Firebase :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three steps to achieving this with Firebase.

1. Give the progtrckr an id.
2. Create a Firebase listener that indicates when the progress is done.
3. Change the style on the element depending on the snapshot's value.

-

```
// #1
var progtrckr = $('#progtrckr');
// #2
var ref = new Firebase('<your-firebase-db>/status');
ref.on('value', function(snap) {
   // #3
   var status = snap.val();
   // Start with a clean slate of classes
   progtrckr.removeClass(); 
   switch (status) {
      case "WASHING":
        progtrckr.addClass('progtrckr-todo');
        break;
      case "DRYING":
        progtrckr.addClass('progtrckr-something');
        break;
      case "READY FOR PICKUP":
        progtrckr.addClass('progtrckr-done');
        break;
   }
});
```

Comment: David, thanks for the quick response.  My question now is getting a little more specific to the application that I'm doing.

I have multiple users in my database, and I will be checking whether the `State` of the user changes.  I'll be checking if the state changes from `Washing`, to  `Drying` to `Ready for Pickup`.  

In var ref = new Firebase() what directory do I link to, if I'm not sure which user will be chosen?

Comment: Open up a new question and I'll have a better format to answer :)

Comment: Actually, wait. Don't worry about another question. I can answer that here.

Comment: Thanks David!  One more question!  Can I make this this `switch` statement update sequentially?  So, once the `status` changes, `Washing` update to done, and if the `status` changes again, `DRYING` updates to done, and so on?

Comment: You can take this same approach but with an object with more information about the status and switch off of that.

Comment: David, this does not seem to be working... even when the `status` is definitely WASHING, the class does not update.  Any ideas why it's not updating when I utilize your code above?

Comment: Nick, I'm not familiar with the way the tracker works. However, the concept above using Firebase is the way to go. If you need more specific help try making a reproducible example on JSBin.